# taking derivative of a polynomial using poly1d polyder without reversing the coefficients

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, polynomials

I'm using poly1d and polyder to return the derivative of a simple polynomial.

```
   3     2
1 x + 1 x + 1 x + 1
```

I'm seeing the simple combination of the two commands doesn't doesn't use the coefficients in the correct order.

```
print(np.poly1d(P.polyder(c)))
```

Is there a one liner that I can use like this

```
print(np.poly1d(P.polyder(c)))
```

so that the coefficients like above are in the correct order?

```
Below is my code and output:

    import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import polynomial as P

print("")

c = (1, 1, 1, 1)

print("the array of coefficients for the polynomial")
print(c)

print("")

print("polynomial with coefficients and exponents")
print(np.poly1d(c))

print("")

print("array of coefficients of derivative of polynomial: lowest order coming first in the array")
d_c = P.polyder(c)
print(d_c)

print("")

print("reversing the array of coefficients for the derivative of the polynomial")
d_c = d_c[::-1]
print(d_c)

print("")

print("printing the derivative of the polynomial with exponents and coefficients")
print(np.poly1d(d_c))

print("")

print("printing the derivative of the polynomial without reversing the coefficient array after derivation")
print(np.poly1d(P.polyder(c)))

print("")
```

Output:

```
the array of coefficients for the polynomial
(1, 1, 1, 1)

polynomial with coefficients and exponents
   3     2
1 x + 1 x + 1 x + 1

array of coefficients of derivative of polynomial: lowest order coming first in the array
[ 1.  2.  3.]

reversing the array of coefficients for the derivative of the polynomial
[ 3.  2.  1.]

printing the derivative of the polynomial with exponents and coefficients
   2
3 x + 2 x + 1

printing the derivative of the polynomial without reversing the coefficient array after derivation
   2
1 x + 2 x + 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `deriv` method on the object you get back from `np.poly1d`:

```
import numpy as np

p = np.poly1d([1, 3, 1, 0, 4])

print(p)
print(p.deriv(1))
```

See [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html) for a full list of available methods.